# How to find and disable a button via JQuery

Tags: jquery, find, closest

I have an input text bind with a lookup button in my html. I want to disable the button and text box for some reasons.

I tried the following but not successful.

```js
var btn = $("#x_Id_armaster").closest(".ew-lookup-list").find(".ew-lookup-btn");
console.log(btn.length)
btn.attr("disabled");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 captionstyle">
        Client <i data-phrase="FieldRequiredIndicator" class="fas fa-asterisk ew-required" data-caption="FieldRequiredIndicator"></i>
    </label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
    <span id="el_s_invoice_Id_armaster">
            <span></span>
    <div class="input-group ew-lookup-list">
      <div class="form-control ew-lookup-text" tabindex="-1" id="lu_x_Id_armaster">
        Please select
      </div>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" title="" class="ew-lookup-btn btn btn-default" onclick="ew.modalLookupShow({lnk:this,el:'x_Id_armaster',m:0,n:10});" ata-original-title="Lookup - Client"><i class="fas fa-search ew-icon"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" data-table="s_invoice" data-field="x_Id_armaster" data-multiple="0" data-lookup="1" data-value-separator=", " name="x_Id_armaster" id="x_Id_armaster" value="" onchange="ew.updateOptions.call(this);">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#x_Id_armaster").closest(".ew-lookup-list")` can't work because `x_Id_armaster` is not inside of `ew-lookup-list`

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just directly use `$('.ew-lookup-btn')`?

Comment: I made you a snippet. You can see the btn is not selected so wrong selector

Comment: `$("#x_Id_armaster").prev().find...` They are on same level - you need to tell us more. Perhaps you have more than one set of the above HTML? Then your ID will not be unique

Comment: Thanks all for reply. Yes, I have more than one lookup buttons in my html. The above block is just one of the lookup field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree, so that's why your code fails.

You can use `closest` with `row` class to find the button. They are the same hierarchy and `closest` worked.

```js
var btn = $("#x_Id_armaster").closest(".row").find(".ew-lookup-btn");
console.log(btn.length)
btn.prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row col-md-12 col-lg-12">
  <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 captionstyle">
              Client <i data-phrase="FieldRequiredIndicator" class="fas fa-asterisk ew-required" data-caption="FieldRequiredIndicator"></i>
       </label>
  <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">

    <span id="el_s_invoice_Id_armaster">
            <span></span>
    <div class="input-group ew-lookup-list">
      <div class="form-control ew-lookup-text" tabindex="-1" id="lu_x_Id_armaster">Please select</div>
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button type="button" title="" class="ew-lookup-btn btn btn-default" onclick="ew.modalLookupShow({lnk:this,el:'x_Id_armaster',m:0,n:10});" ata-original-title="Lookup - Client"><i class="fas fa-search ew-icon"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" data-table="s_invoice" data-field="x_Id_armaster" data-multiple="0" data-lookup="1" data-value-separator=", " name="x_Id_armaster" id="x_Id_armaster" value="" onchange="ew.updateOptions.call(this);">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#x_Id_armaster .ew-lookup-btn').attr("disabled", true);
```

Explanation:

`$("#x_Id_armaster").closest(".ew-lookup-list").find(".ew-lookup-btn");` is pretty heavy and wrong considering your markup. It will be quicker and pimplier to just use `'#x_Id_armaster .ew-lookup-btn'` as a selector.

**attr** method requires second argument, eg.

```
.attr("disabled", true)
```

And here is how to do it without using jQuery:

```
 document.querySelector('#x_Id_armaster .ew-lookup-list').disabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks Volodymyr for the fast advice. I have more than one lookup button carrying same class thus I have to find the correct one thru the nearest object that's why I have to find the button from $('#_Id_armaster'). Your script works but it disabled all lookup buttons.

Comment: hmmm... both "document.querySelector('#x_Id_armaster .ew-lookup-list')" and $('#x_Id_armaster .ew-lookup-btn') return null.  anyway, I use Shree suggestion of using $("#x_Id_armaster").closest(".row").find(".ew-lookup-btn"); this works. Thanks for you help!